# Can I do a RegisterType in one project and Resolve this interface in another project using Unity Containers?

Tags: c#, uwp, unity-container

I have a VS solution A which contains an interface foo

```
public interface IFoo
{
 //some methods
}
```

I have a solution B which implements this Interface

```
public class Bar : IFoo
{ 
  //methods implemented here
}
```

App.xaml.cs in Solution B uses unity container to register this

App.xaml.cs

//code

```
this.unityContainer.RegisterType<IFoo, Bar>();
```

Now in solution A, can I resolve IFoo?

SOLn A

```
Class A
{
   this.unityContainer.resolve<IFoo>(); //get error here
}
```

Since the type IFoo, Bar is not registered in the same solution, I get the error a type cannot be resolved. Is there a workaround which makes this possible?

Comment: Don't you mean "project" rather than "solution" ?

Comment: Yes. Edited it to say project. Thanks!

Comment: DO you have more than one istance of the container...? Where and how are you instantiating `unityContainer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no difference in what project you do a registrations as far as you "share" one unity container between projects.

It's a standard way of registering dependencies - but remember! you have to share the ioc container instance some way.

Example

#Project A (no dependencies)

```
interface IFoo {}
```

#Project B (depends on A)

```
unityContainer.RegisterType<IFoo, Bar>();
```

#Project C (depends on A)

```
unityContainer.resolve<IFoo>();
```

But agin, you have to share the `UnityContainer` instance some way. Usually there is `Main` project that acts like a "glue" between those projects.

I can recommend a great book about dependecy inection:
https://www.manning.com/books/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns

because you have to understood basic principles and mechanisms.